# alternative to cordova.addConstructor?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using a PhoneGap Plug in with register itself like this

```
// Register the plugin

cordova.addConstructor(function () {
  window.pushNotification =  new PushNotification();
});
```

I need to use CORDOVA at VERSION 2.5.0, so for my understanding cordova.addConstructor( has been removed in version.

Which API is more appropriate instead taking in consideration what must be also compatible with CORDOVA VERSION 2.1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use addConstructor anymore, just do:

```
        if (!window.plugins) {
            window.plugins = {};
        }
        window.plugins.pushNotification = new PushNotification();
```

Or I guess since you don't seem to be using a plugins object, just
`window.pushNotification = new PushNotification()`

I tested this with a mock application on 2.0 and 2.5 and both worked.

Although you asked for 2.5, I just want to point out that when you go to update this plugin for use with 2.6, it is [recommended to wrap your plugin in a module](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/wiki/Defining-Your-Cordova-Plugin-As-A-Cordova-Module).

Comment: What is window.plugins anyway? I checked that javascript window object has no property like plugins. I guess it's just a new jSON object we are setting into the window object. Is that right? Thanks

Comment: Hi. Yes, correct, in the older versions of Cordova (like 2.6ish, before plugins were written as an AMD module and before core functionality was split out into plugins) it was just an object that we created on window and added the third party plugins to, mostly for ease of access. If you look, you are already doing things like `navigator.accelerometer.setWatch`. In this case, we are attaching the `accelerometer` plugin code to the navigator object, instead of our 'window.plugins' object. (It's a little hard to explain since the definition of `plugins` has expanded so much in Cordova 3.0

Comment: Thanks again. I think although a bit different from Java, I am now getting interested in js coding as well.

Comment: Yup you're welcome. Java and JavaScript are a lot different. Personally I think JS is way more fun!